# Increase sample size via algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, normal-distribution, python

If I have a normally distributed dataset with a sample size of 100, what algorithms/procedures can I implement to increase the sample size to 1000?

Comment: What do you mean by "increasing sample size"?

Comment: I would like to maintain the normal distribution of the dataset, but randomly add 900 points to the distribution such that the sample size has increased to 1000.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. If the data is truthly normally distributted just use random number generator to draw next 900 cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect data, but you cannot make data.

If I have 80 years of stock returns going back to 1930, and that's all there is, then that's all there is. I cannot magically get 200 years of stock returns. Where are the extra 120 years of stock data supposedly going to come from?!

Comment: That makes sense. I was wondering if there was some sort of cautious extrapolation method that could be applied.

Comment: @JakeSmith That wouldn't generate more data though. All your estimation would still be a function of the original 100 data points. You hypothetically could do all kinds of fancy, interpolation, weirdo fitting etc... and you still would only have 100 degrees of freedom to your input because it's only 100 data points.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thank you for your answers, I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Of course, you're always allowed to fit some curve using your data, then from estimated curve, generate thousands upon thousands of points so you can make a nice plot of the estimated curve. That's perfectly legit.